# Default Date for UIDatePicker in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uidatepicker

I am new in iOS development. I have this ViewController in my Storyboard (includes a UIDatePicker and a bar button):

[image]

I followed [Data Cell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html) to call my DatePicker. When user click on a button in the page PickerDate pops up with a done bar button on the navigation bar:

[image]

The problem is it shows just the current date as `default`. Nothing changes when I set it from Properties:

[image]

Do you know how can I fix it? (by `setting up the properties` or programmatically).

Comment: Add it programmatically and there you can set accordingly ....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did it programmatically in this way :

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[components setYear:1980];
[components setMonth:1];
[components setDay:1];
NSDate *defualtDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
pickerView.date = defualtDate;
```

But still don't know why it doesn't work by `setting up the properties`. Any help?

Comment: Does you have set the `IBOutlate` to the pickerView ? :)

Comment: Yes, I exactly done what you coded. My question is do we have to set it always programmatically? Look at my image on properties page. Can we fix it from there?

Comment: Actually it should work from there also but not happend like we expect :( . So have to do it programmatically always :) .

Comment: You think that it's a bug in iOS? do you have the same problem?

Comment: May be but not sure about it :)

Answer (score 4):

In **Swift**:

```
let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")!
let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
components.year = 1980
components.month = 1 
components.day = 1
let defaultDate: NSDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
self.dateOfBirthUIDatePicker.date = defaultDate
```

Answer (score 2):

Great answers above - Here's the **Swift3** (Feb 17) version:

```
let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier:  .gregorian)!
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone
let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
components.year = 1980
components.month = 1
components.day = 1
let defaultDate: NSDate = calendar.date(from: components as DateComponents)! as NSDate
self.datePicker.date = defaultDate as Date
```