# UIDatePicker change default selected row

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uidatepicker

There is UIDatePicker in my app. I have set it's mode as "Time".

In it's default selected row current time showing. So how to change it?

I want to display 9:00 AM as default selected, does't matter what is current time.

I have tried with below code,

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"9:00 a"];
[myDatePicker setDate:date];
```

but, it's getting crashed with "Invalid parameter not satisfying: date"

Can anybody help me out here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843185/default-date-for-uidatepicker-in-ios

Comment: I will put it into the answer so you can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of problems with setting up the properties in the interface builder but at this link you can find everything you need:

[Default Date for UIDatePicker in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843185/default-date-for-uidatepicker-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

The Mode of Date Picker is "Time".
Add two more property to get the default custom value.

1. Set Date property as "Custom"
2. In the below test box, provide a default value which the picker needs to display. (As Time property is selected for date picker, while providing default value - dates can be ignored)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gati..! you may mark it as 'answer' if it helped you..!